# Excel lookup formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use a formula to get sum of one item from a Column that contains several items.

[image]

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do.  By definition, a sum is the addition of multiple items.  If you want a single value, you would need a formula that identifies that value.  It would help to add a specific example to your question to illustrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum, for example, the SLEEVE items,

```
=SUMIF(C4:C39,"SLEEVE",D4:D39)
```